# boto3 query using KeyConditionExpression

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm having trouble understanding why below query on a DynamoDB table doesn't work:

```
dict_table.query(KeyConditionExpression='norm = :cihan', ExpressionAttributeValues={':cihan': {'S': 'cihan'}})
```

and throws this error:

`ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: Condition parameter type does not match schema type`

while the following works:

```
dict_table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('norm').eq('cihan'))
```

`norm` is a field with type string. I'm using boto3 v 1.4.0 and [following the docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.query):

```
In [43]: boto3.__version__
Out[43]: '1.4.0'
```

Can anyone see what's the error in the first query?

Bonus question: What's with all the tokens and the need to replace them all the time? Why can't I just say `dict_table.query(KeyConditionExpression='norm = cihan')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please change the ExpressionAttributeValues as mentioned below.

```
ExpressionAttributeValues={':cihan': 'cihan'}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! But why do the Boto3 document give the following example? `{ ":avail":{"S":"Available"}, ":back":{"S":"Backordered"}, ":disc":{"S":"Discontinued"} }` See http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.query

Comment: I agree, the docs are misleading. They make it seem like the values of the dictionary you provide for ExpressionAttributeValues, should themselves be dictionaries with keys such as 'S', 'B', and 'N', whereas I think it's just trying to indicate that those are the possible types of the values.

Comment: On second thoughts, it just seems incorrect. Perhaps from a previous version of the boto3 API.

Answer (score 2):

In current versions of boto3 (1.9.128) the query mentioned in the question asked works fine, and nothing else apart from that is working now, the query mentioned below worked for me:-

`dynamo_client.query(
    KeyConditionExpression='campaign_id = :201906',
    ExpressionAttributeValues={':201906': {'S': '201906'}}
)`

Answer (score 2):

### The bonus question...

To answer your bonus question, all the tokens are a layer of abstraction dynamo uses to ensure type consistency across the http requests made when its communicated with. Using standard http/json there is room for ambiguity in cases like "2" and 2. So, dynamo forces the client to wrap values in objects that specifically define their type.

### Back to the original question...

With that said... its kind of ridiculous the boto3 API doesn't abstract that away for you. Although I can understand its a little out of the scope of the boto3 tool. **There is hope** in a library called [dynamof](https://github.com/rayepps/dynamof). Using it your query would look like:

```py
from boto3 import client
from dynamof import db as make_db
from dynamof import query

client = client('dynamodb', endpoint_url='http://localstack:4569')
db = make_db(client)

results = db(query(
    table_name='dict_table',
    conditions=attr('norm').equals('cihan')
))
```

You get the same simple API for making dynamo requests in other commonly used operations like creating a table, adding an item, updating, deleting, and scanning. More operations and features are in dev now.

*disclaimer: I wrote dynamof*